# How to create datetime object from character datetime and timezone columns?

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

I have a dataframe with dates saved in one column and the corresponding time zone in another, both in character format. The dates are local dates in the respective timezone noted in the timezone column, not UTC.

```
data_frame = data.frame(eventid = c(1:4),
                        start = c("2021-05-05 01:04:34",
                                  "2021-03-06 03:14:44",
                                  "2021-03-11 07:22:48",
                                  "2021-02-02 11:54:56") ,
                        start_timezone = c("Europe/Berlin",
                                         "Europe/Berlin",
                                         "Europe/Berlin",
                                         "Indian/Maldives")
)
```

I need to convert the date column into datetime objects that take the differing timezones into account, but feeding the text timezone to any function has not worked for me, e.g.

```
data_frame %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(start_in_zone= as.POSIXct(start, tz = start_timezone))
```

How would I approach this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `lubridate` package, you need first to transform your data as date, then force the timezone with `with_tz()`

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)


df %>% 
  mutate(l_start = ymd_hms(start)) %>% 
  group_by(start_timezone) %>% 
  mutate(start_local = with_tz(l_start, start_timezone)) %>% 
  select(-l_start)


# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   start_timezone [2]
  eventid start               start_timezone  start_local        
    <int> <chr>               <chr>           <dttm>             
1       1 2021-05-05 01:04:34 Europe/Berlin   2021-05-05 03:04:34
2       2 2021-03-06 03:14:44 Europe/Berlin   2021-03-06 04:14:44
3       3 2021-03-11 07:22:48 Europe/Berlin   2021-03-11 08:22:48
4       4 2021-02-02 11:54:56 Indian/Maldives 2021-02-02 12:54:56
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `as_datetime` function to change the time to UTC.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data_frame %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(UTC_time= as_datetime(start, tz = start_timezone) %>% 
                        as_datetime(tz = 'UTC')) %>%
  ungroup

#   eventid start               start_timezone  UTC_time           
#    <int> <chr>               <chr>           <dttm>             
#1       1 2021-05-05 01:04:34 Europe/Berlin   2021-05-04 23:04:34
#2       2 2021-03-06 03:14:44 Europe/Berlin   2021-03-06 02:14:44
#3       3 2021-03-11 07:22:48 Europe/Berlin   2021-03-11 06:22:48
#4       4 2021-02-02 11:54:56 Indian/Maldives 2021-02-02 06:54:56
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R is something of a rabbit hole for the unwary (of which I are one), but assume you have your df named on_tzs:

```
on_tzs <- structure(list(eventid = 1:4, start = c("2021-05-05 01:04:34", 
"2021-03-06 03:14:44", "2021-03-11 07:22:48", "2021-02-02 11:54:56"
), start_timezone = c("Europe/Berlin", "Europe/Berlin", "Europe/Berlin", 
"Indian/Maldives")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

and you have a burning desire to arrive at `$start_in_zone`, you'd be helping things along by preparing the nest for the wild POSIX to settle into:

```
on_tzs['start_in_zone'] <- NA_character_ 
class(on_tzs$start_in_zone) <- c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
class(on_tzs$start_in_zone)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

and then move on to populating $start_in_zone

```
for (i in 1:4) {
on_tzs$start_in_zone[i] <- strftime(x = on_tzs$start[i], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%OS', tz = on_tzs$start_timezone[i], usetz = TRUE)
 }
on_tzs
  eventid               start  start_timezone       start_in_zone
1       1 2021-05-05 01:04:34   Europe/Berlin 2021-05-05 01:05:34
2       2 2021-03-06 03:14:44   Europe/Berlin 2021-03-06 03:03:44
3       3 2021-03-11 07:22:48   Europe/Berlin 2021-03-11 07:03:48
4       4 2021-02-02 11:54:56 Indian/Maldives 2021-02-02 11:02:56
```

Hey wait!, where's the tz?

```
print(on_tzs$start_in_zone)
[1] "2021-05-05 01:05:34 CEST" "2021-03-06 03:03:44 CET" 
[3] "2021-03-11 07:03:48 CET"  "2021-02-02 11:02:56 CET"
```

Hey wait!, #4 is wrong!

```
# an argument seems to be developing for using `lubridate` to preserve sanity
```